# How to share cached data across subdomains in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I share cached data across subdomains in AngularJS?  All of our apps are hosted using subdomains and a good portion of the data is common (all stored within Local storage).  For example:

```
app001.myapp.com
app002.myapp.com
...
app209.myapp.com
app210.myapp.com
```

We have a ton of resource data that is currently being fetched repeatedly by the applications.

Comment: @Makoto this shouldn't be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Angular's responsibility.  This is the API's responsibility.

You generally want to have an API call that can either retrieve a cached result, or fetches from the database and caches the result for a period of time.

Comment: How was that helpful?  I realize this functionality isn't NATIVE to Angular, but that goes 90% of what is discussed here... how to do something, regardless if it is native or not.  I'm simply trying to find a tool that will allow this to happen within Angular.

Comment: @G.Deward:  The main thing you're looking to do is share data across multiple web servers to your web application.  In an ideal world, the web application simply asks for the data; it shouldn't matter *where* the data comes from as long as it isn't stale.  That is by and large handled at a layer below, typically with your server stack.